# convert a bitmapImage to byte array for windows store

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I need to know how to convert a bitmap-image to a byte array for windows store application.
Here is what I have tried but it does not store the bitmapImage

```
    Dim file As StorageFile = Await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync()
    Dim stream As IRandomAccessStream = Await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read)
    Dim decoder As BitmapDecoder = Await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream)
    Dim pixelData As PixelDataProvider = Await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync()
    Return pixelData.DetachPixelData()
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: What code have you tried so far? If you show what you've tried, and say which bit doesn't work, then you'll find you'll get a better response.

Comment: well i tried this but it's not store like a  bitmapImage
 ' Dim file As StorageFile = Await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync()
        

        Dim stream As IRandomAccessStream = Await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read)
       Dim decoder As BitmapDecoder = Await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream)
        Dim pixelData As PixelDataProvider = Await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync()
        Return pixelData.DetachPixelData()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it :D

```
Async Function bitmapTObyte(ByVal bitmapimage1 As StorageFile) As Task(Of Byte())
    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = Nothing
    Using stream As IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType = Await bitmapimage1.OpenReadAsync()
        fileBytes = New Byte(stream.Size - 1) {}
        Using reader As New DataReader(stream)
            Await reader.LoadAsync(CUInt(stream.Size))
            reader.ReadBytes(fileBytes)
            Return fileBytes
        End Using
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the bitmap to `MemoryStream` with `Bitmap.Save()` and then save the `MemoryStream.ToArray()`. Maybe not the most elegant approach, but works.
I can post a working code a bit later.

Comment: i can covert `Byte()` to `BitmapImage` but  in reverse i couldn't and i need this so much

Comment: Why don't you just save the stream to array? See if this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21429952/c-sharp-convert-bitmapimage-object-to-bytearray

Comment: And I believe this link has a working solution http://amoore.katalyststudios.com/content/reading-storagefile-byte-array-c

Comment: i'm working on project that store a bitmapImage to sql server and that image should be shown in the windows store app and in the windows phone too so i should use the same way to show it in both ....i could find it in windows phone (bitmapImage to byte()) and (byte to bitmapImage) but in windows store app i  only found  byte to bitmapImage i'm trying to find reverse ...i'hope that you understand me ...

Comment: and about the storage file i try it but when you want to take from data base and convert it to bitmapImage ... not working